# How can I copy and edit flash layers, without them all changing? (CS5)

Tags: flash, templates, copy, flash-cs5, layer

I've been trying to copy a layer of a flash file and use it as a makeshift template, but whenever I change the layer *every* copy of the template is changed. There are multiple movie clips and buttons and text within the layer, but the problem remains when I change the instance names (or the layer name for that matter).

Is there a way around this? I've tried copying the frames as well, but even then the changes carry through. Is it possible to separate a copied layer from the original (once and for all!?)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are modifying an object which is an instance of a library object causing the library object (and all the instances from that library object) to change. Try making a copy of the object in the library and using that instead. You could also select the objects, right click and choose 'duplicate symbol' to make a copy of it in the library.

Comment: It verks! Thank you! Can't believe I didn't think of it though!